# How to get the Typed Abstract Syntaxt Tree from F# Compiler Service

Tags: f#, f#-compiler-services

How can I access the typed abstract syntaxe tree for all source files in a f# project in order as descibed in ["analysing a whole project"](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/project.html). So, what I need is the specific Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Tast of all files in a project.

Accessing the untyped syntax tree is quite simple, as described in [walking an untyped ast](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/untypedtree.html). So, I expect there to be a corresponding interface to the tast.

The purpose is to transpile code from F# to another typed language, in this case scala, which need type annotations. A whole project should be translated at once.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why?

Comment: The purpose is to transpile *small* pieces of  code from F# to another typed language, in this case scala.

Answer (score 1):

The first URL you link shows how to get an `FSharpAssemblySignature`, but doesn't explain much of what to do with such a value.  That type, and the immediate types it contains, `FSharpEntity` & `FSharpMemberOrFunctionOrValue`, are defined in [Symbols.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/vs/Symbols.fs).  The typed AST itself is defined in [tast.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/tast.fs).  I don't know of any docs explaining the various types, except the comments in these two files.